# Get the username list from keycloak and save it to an array for later use

Tags: node.js, keycloak, httpresponse, rest, keycloak-rest-api

i am trying to write code to retrive all users who exist in the keycloak user list.i am getting all the users inside the keycloak. but i want to get only the usernames or ids from the full list of users and store that value inside an array which i can use to assign role to user

**myfile.cs**

```
let userName = []
function GetUser(userName,kc_accessToken) {
    let url = `${path}/users`;
    return axios_instance.get(url,
      {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "authorization": `Bearer ${kc_accessToken}`
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
        console.log("User names!!");

       //full list (working)
       //userName = response.data
       //console.log(response.data);

       //only usernames or ids (not working)
        userName = response.data.username 
        console.log(response.data.username);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("No Users");
      });
  }
```

**function call**

```
http.createServer(function Test() {
    getAccessToken().then(function (response) {
        kc_accessToken = response.data.access_token;

        GetUser(userName,kc_accessToken).then((resp) => {
        })


    }).catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    })
        .then(function () {
            // always executed
        });;
}).listen(8081);
```

my output when i try to list all users

[image]

my output when i am trying to get only usernames of the users

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an array of user objects in `response.data`, so you can simply apply a map function to generate an array of strings containing the users names:

`const usernames = response.data.map(user => user.username)`

Comment: wow it works well thank you so much. Have a great day